# How do I install clang-format on Debian 8.11?

Tags: debian, clang, clang-format, debian-jessie

I tried

```
sudo apt install clang-format
```

but I get the following error:

> E: Unable to locate package clang-format

Answer (score 1):

The package is available from Jessie-backports.

Add backports to your sources.list :

```
echo "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then install [`clang-format`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/clang-format-6.0):

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install clang-format-6.0
```

The package is only available from jessie backports you can just type:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install clang-format-6.0
```

You should run the above commands as root or using `sudo` if its is already installed.